# About Aubin-Lions Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compact-operators

I am trying to study an example on how to apply Aubin-lions Lemma, but i dont get why some things happen, so first, i state the lemma

**(Aubin-Lions)** Let $E_{0} \subset E \subset E_{1}$ be three Banach spaces, with compact embedding $E_{0} \subset E$ (bounded sets of $E_{0}$ are relatively compact in $E$ ) and continuous embedding $E \subset E_{1} .$ Let $p, q \geq 1 .$ Then
$$
L^{p}\left(0, T ; E_{0}\right) \cap W^{1, q}\left(0, T ; E_{1}\right)
$$
is compactly embedded into
$$
L^{p}(0, T ; E)
$$

And the PDE where i want to apply the lemma is

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &=\Delta u+b(u) \cdot \nabla u+c(u) \\
\left.u\right|_{t=0} &=u_{0},\left.\quad u\right|_{\partial D}=0
\end{aligned}

where D is an open Domain in the reals. So i can find that for a possible weak solution $u_n$, $u_n$ is bounded in $L^2(0,T:H^1(D))$ and $\frac{du_{n}}{dt}$ is bounded in $L^2(0,T:H^{-1}(D))$. So after this the notes that i'm studying conclude the following

*Using Aubin lemma we have that
$$
E_{0}=W^{1,2}(D), E=L^{2}(D), E_{1}=W^{-1,2}
$$
and use in essential way the compactness of the embedding $W^{1,2}(D) \subset L^{2}(D)$ (Rellich theorem). We deduce that $\left\{u_{n}\right\}$ is relatively compact in $L^{2}\left(0, T ; L^{2}(D)\right)$ in the strong topology (this is the important information in order to pass to the limit in nonlinear terms). The sequence is also weakly relatively compact in $L^{2}\left(0, T ; W^{1,2}(D)\right)$ and weak star relatively compact in $C\left([0, T] ; L^{2}(D)\right) .$ Then there exists a subsequence which converges in all these three topologies to a function $u$ which is then of class $L^{2}\left(0, T ; W^{1,2}(D)\right)$ and $C\left([0, T] ; L^{2}(D)\right) .$ Thanks to the strong convergence in $L^{2}\left(0, T ; L^{2}(D)\right)$ one can pass to the limit and prove that $u$ is a solution.*

So, first of all i would like to know what weakly relatively compact means.

Second, how do we know that $u_n$ is weak star relatively compact in $C\left([0, T] ; L^{2}(D)\right) .$

And, how can we conlude that there exist a subsequence which converges in all these three topologies (what topologies does the author mean) to a function $u$ which is then of class $L^{2}\left(0, T ; W^{1,2}(D)\right)$ and $C\left([0, T] ; L^{2}(D)\right) .$

Thank you in advance and i really hope u can help me.

Comment: It is not clear what the weak$^\ast$ topology on $C([0,T];L^2(D))$ is supposed to be. At least scalar-valued $C([0,T])$ is not a dual space (unless $T=0$).

Comment: That is one of the facts that makes that conclusion confusing for me, prob working with $L^{\infty}$ would be ok, instead of $C([0,T]:L^2(D))$, but anyways this weakly relatively concept is new for me and can't get enough details on what does it mean